# How to project sub-document values in an array using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am creating an application that needs to support multiple languages in the content. I am using the following document structure; each field that needs translation is an object with each language and associated string.

```
{
  "greeting": {
    "en": "Hello",
    "fr": "Bonjou"
  },
  "places": [
    {
      "name": {
        "en": "CN Tower",
        "fr": "La Tour CN"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "en": "Skydome",
        "fr": "Le Skydome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to aggregate the result into a single selected language to produce the following result.

```
{
  "greeting": "Hello",
  "places": [
    {
      "name": "CN Tower"
    },
    {
      "name": "Skydome"
    }
  ]
}
```

Mapping the `greeting` field was simple, requiring only a `$greeting.en`. However, sub-documents in an array are a lot trickier to perform the path syntax with. Instead, I've had to use a `$map` to achieve the result I needed.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    greeting: "$greeting.en",
    places: {
      $map: {
        input: "$places",
        as: "place",
        in: { name: "$$place.name.en"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

Is there a way to achieve this without using `$map` and instead using the path syntax?

Comment: Instead of lifting keys in the query I imagine you could perform projection in the query (returning keys with `en` in them) and perform the lifting in the application.

Comment: @D.SM it's a consideration, but the database is generally going to do this more quickly and it keeps the transformation logic closer to the data layer.